# MVC index to edit with new (enhanced view model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, ef-code-first

(edited)
I have a table with products (Products) which is being displayed in a view called ProductCatalog, where a user would find all products that are in the products table. I am using the standard (Index) view for that.

What I now want to achieve is a scenario where an individual product from the catalog can be selected (clicked) and a detail view of the product would appear (similar to the standard Edit/Details approach in CRUD). **However**, in this details view (ProductDetails) I need to enhance the model as a user would determine variables such as order quantity which should be posted to a new table (LineItems) along with attributes from the product (ProductID, primarily) to ultimately create an order.

I keep on failing to achieve this. Not sure whether I need to use mutliple viewmodels or do some other fancy stuff I don't know about.

So in summary, the question is how to get from Index to Details and from Details to post a different viewmodel to some DB. All of that with EF.

Model:

```
    public class Products
{
    public int                                                      ID                                  { get; set; }
    public int                                                      CategoryID                          { get; set; }
    public string                                                   ProductName                         { get; set; }
    public string                                                   ProductDescription                  { get; set; }
    public string                                                   ProductPicturePath                  { get; set; }
    public string                                                   UnitCost                            { get; set; }
    public string                                                   UnitPrice                           { get; set; }
    public string                                                   LowestUnitPrice                     { get; set; }
    public string                                                   SubscriptionPrice                   { get; set; }
    public string                                                   UnitMargin                          { get; set; }
    public string                                                   UnitProfit                          { get; set; }
    public bool                                                     InCatalog                           { get; set; }
}


    public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int                                                      ProductID                           { get; set; }

    public string                                                   ProductName                         { get; set; }

    public string                                                   ProductDescription                  { get; set; }

    public string                                                   ProductPicturePath                  { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\((\d{3}?)\)$", ErrorMessage              = "Du brauchst die Anzahl nicht ausschreiben - verwende Ziffern.")]
    [Display(Name                                                   = "Bestellmenge")]
    public string                                                   SubscriptionQuantity                { get; set; }

    [Display(Name                                                   = "Lieferrhytmus")]
    public string                                                   SubscriptionCadenceCategory         { get; set; }

    public string                                                   SubscriptionCadenceValue            { get; set; }

    [Display(Name                                                   = "Preis im Abonnement")]
    public string                                                   SubscriptionPrice                   { get; set; }

    public bool                                                     IsSingleOrder                       { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\((\d{3}?)\)$", ErrorMessage              = "Du brauchst die Anzahl nicht ausschreiben - verwende Ziffern.")]
    [Display(Name                                                   = "Bestellmenge")]
    public string                                                   Quantity                            { get; set; }

    [Display(Name =                                                 "Preis pro Einheit")]
    public string                                                   UnitPrice                           { get; set; }

    public DateTime                                                 ActivityDateTime                    { get; set; }

    public string                                                   ActivityLatitude                    { get; set; }

    public string                                                   ActivityLongitude                   { get; set; }

    public string                                                   ActivityLocation                    { get; set; }


}
```

View

```
@using freshNclean.Models
@model IEnumerable<freshNclean.Models.Products>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sortiment";
}
<div id="productCatalogContainer" class="container">
    <div id="productCatalogHeaderSection" class="headerSection">
        <h1 id="productCatalogHeaderTitle" class="headerTitle">
            @ViewBag.Title
        </h1>
        <i id="productCatalogHeaderIcon" class="headerIcon fas fa-gem" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
<!-- table section -->
    <section id="productCatalogListPartialSection" class="table">
        <div id="productCatalogSeparatorSection" class="separatorSection">
            <hr id="productCatalogSeparator" class="separator" />
        </div>
        <div id="productCatalog" class="productTableSection row">
             @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if (item.InCatalog == true)
                {
                    <a id="productCatalogProductArea" class="tableArea col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-3" href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "freshNclean", new { id = item.ID })">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID, new { @class = "tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" })
                        <img id="productCatalogProductImage" class="tableImage col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" src="@Url.Content(item.ProductPicturePath)" alt="Produktbild" />
                        <div id="productCatalogProductNameField" class="tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                        </div>
                        <div id="productCatalogProductDescriptionField" class="tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDescription)
                        </div>

                        <div id="productCatalogLowestUnitPriceField" class="tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                            ab @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LowestUnitPrice)
                        </div>
                    </a>
                }
            }
        </div>

        <div id="productCatalogListPartialMenuSeparatorSection" class="separatorSection">
            <hr id="productCatalogListPartialMenuSeparator" class="separator" />
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("zum Warenkorb", "ShowShoppingCart", "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6" })
    </section>
</div>
<!-- link back to menu -->
<div id="productCatalogReturnToMenuSection" class="linkSection">
    @Html.ActionLink("zurück zum Menü", "Profile", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "productCatalogReturnToMenuButton", @class = "link" })
</div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<!-- Google Places -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYK8aBCsb1dFrzXqIgUq07ZwO3w3_fGCs&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
}
```

ProductDetails (View)

```
@model freshNclean.Models.Products
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sortiment";
}
<div id="productCatalogContainer" class="container">
<div id="productCatalogHeaderSection" class="headerSection">
    <h1 id="productCatalogHeaderTitle" class="headerTitle">
        @ViewBag.Title
    </h1>
    <i id="productCatalogHeaderIcon" class="headerIcon fas fa-gem" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<!-- form -->
<section id="productDetailsForm" class="form">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ShowProduct", "freshNclean", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "productDetailsFormContainer", @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<!-- user activities (hidden) -->
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityLatitude, new { @id = "productDetailsActivityLatitudeField", @class = "userActivityField" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityLongitude, new { @id = "productDetailsActivityLongitudeField", @class = "userActivityField" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ActivityLocation, new { @id = "productDetailsActivityLocationField", @class = "userActivityField" })
<!-- autopopulate user activity fields with location -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function defaultValue() {
                if (!navigator.geolocation) return;
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (userCoordinates) {
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(userCoordinates.coords.latitude, userCoordinates.coords.longitude);
                    document.getElementById('productDetailsActivityLatitudeField').value = userCoordinates.coords.latitude;
                    document.getElementById('productDetailsActivityLongitudeField').value = userCoordinates.coords.longitude;
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': userLatLng }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var result = results[0];
                            locationPlaceholder = "";
                            for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
                                var addressComponent = result.address_components[i];
                                if (addressComponent.types.indexOf("locality") >= 0) locationPlaceholder = addressComponent.long_name;
                            }
                            if (locationPlaceholder != '') {
                                document.getElementById('productDetailsActivityLocationField').value = locationPlaceholder;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
<!-- form: product display -->
        <div id="productDetailsProductDisplaySeparatorSection" class="separatorSection">
            <hr id="productDetailsProductDisplaySeparator" class="separator" />
        </div>
        <div id="productDetailsProductDisplaySection" class="formSection row">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductID, new { @id = "productDetailsProductIDField", @class = "tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" })
            <img id="productDetailsProductImage" class="tableImage col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" src="@Model.ProductPicturePath" alt="Produktbild" />
            <div id="productDetailsProductName" class="tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductName)
            </div>
            <div id="productDetailsProductDescriptionField" class="tableField col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProductDescription)
            </div>
<!-- define subscription quantity -->
            <a id="productDetailsSubscriptionMinusButton" class="tableButton col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-3 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-2">
                -
            </a>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubscriptionQuantity, new { @id = "productDetailsSubscriptionQuantityField", @class = "tableField col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-2" placeholder = "0" })
            <a id="productDetailsSubscriptionPlusButton" class="tableButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-2">
                +
            </a>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubscriptionCadenceCategory, new { @id = "productDetailsSubscriptionCadenceCategoryLabel", @class = "tableLabel" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubscriptionCadenceCategory, new { @id = "productDetailsSubscriptionCadenceCategoryField", @class= "tableField" })
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubscriptionCadenceValue, new { @id = "productDetailsSubscriptionCadenceValueLabel", @class = "tableLabel" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubscriptionCadenceValue, new { @id = "productDetailsSubscriptionCadenceValueField", @class= "tableField" })

        </div>

        <div id="productCatalogListPartialMenuSeparatorSection" class="separatorSection">
            <hr id="productCatalogListPartialMenuSeparator" class="separator" />
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("zum Warenkorb", "ShowShoppingCart", "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formButton col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6" })
    </section>
</div>
<!-- link back to menu -->
<div id="productCatalogReturnToMenuSection" class="linkSection">
    @Html.ActionLink("zurück zum Menü", "Profile", "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "productCatalogReturnToMenuButton", @class = "link" })
</div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<!-- Google Places -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBYK8aBCsb1dFrzXqIgUq07ZwO3w3_fGCs&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
}
```

Controller

```
        // GET: /freshNclean/ProductDetails
    public ActionResult ShowProduct(int? id)
    {
        // define variables
        var userID                                                  = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        DateTime nowUTC                                             = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime nowLocal                                           = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
        if (id                                                      == null)
        {
            // track user activity: get method includes activity name and timestamp without location
            var NOPRODUCTID                                         = new UserActivities
            {
                UserID                                              = userID,
                ActivityName                                        = "ProductDetails_NoProductID",
                ActivityTimeStampUTC                                = nowUTC,
                ActivityLatitude                                    = "n/a",
                ActivityLongitude                                   = "n/a",
                ActivityLocation                                    = "n/a"
            };
            DATADB.UserActivityList.Add(NOPRODUCTID);
            DATADB.SaveChanges();
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Products model                                              = DATADB.ProductList.Find(id);
        if(model == null)
        {
            // track user activity: get method includes activity name and timestamp without location
            var PRODUCTSMODELFAILURE                                = new UserActivities
            {
                UserID                                              = userID,
                ActivityName                                        = "ProductDetails_ProductsModelFailure",
                ActivityTimeStampUTC                                = nowUTC,
                ActivityLatitude                                    = "n/a",
                ActivityLongitude                                   = "n/a",
                ActivityLocation                                    = "n/a"
            };
            DATADB.UserActivityList.Add(PRODUCTSMODELFAILURE);
            DATADB.SaveChanges();
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        // track user activity: get method includes activity name and timestamp without location
        var LOADED                                                  = new UserActivities
        {
            UserID                                                  = userID,
            ActivityName                                            = "ProductDetails_Loaded",
            ActivityTimeStampUTC                                    = nowUTC,
            ActivityLatitude                                        = "n/a",
            ActivityLongitude                                       = "n/a",
            ActivityLocation                                        = "n/a"
        };
        DATADB.UserActivityList.Add(LOADED);
        DATADB.SaveChanges();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what is blocking you. If you have the product's ID why not just query the database, map the result into a new ViewModel like `ProductDetailsViewModel` and display it ? This doesn't have to be the same ViewModel as the one used to display the catalogue at all !

Comment: Thank you.. I just not don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Wndrr - would you be so kind and provide an example? What I am trying to do is to get from the Index view (which is basically displaying the list from a table) to the individual rows.. but the rows are actually enhanced with more information.

Comment: I created an answer. Let me know if this helped you. If not, please re-explain your problem and add your code attempt to help me understand what is blocking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: For technical reasons I was not able to run this code. For this reason it might contain un-caught bugs. Let me know of any such things.

So, here is a far too complete example. 
The idea is as follow:

- We call the index view
- We get all the users from the database and store the list in our ViewModel (we could have done without it by only passing the list of `PersonEntity`)
- We display the view which lists all the persons using a HTML table
- When we click the `Details` link we get sent to the `DetailRow` action. The `person.Id` is passed as a GET parameter.
- **In the `DetailRow` view we query the database but only request the `PersonEntity` that matches the `Id` passed as parameter.**
- **We ask entity framework to include the `Detail` property using the `.Include` method.**
- **We return the result that we got, which will be a single `PersonEntity` after mapping into a view model.**
- We display the returned `Person` in the `DetailRow` view

The bold lines are the ones that I think directly answer your question. 
In this example I assumed that you used Entity Framework, if not you will need to "translate" the calls to the `Context` class to a DAO of some sort, or in-line SQL if you're a dirty guy ;-)

The code for the controller & data layer (ideally you would have each class in its own file)

```
public class KenFExample : Controller
{
    // GET
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            // Get the whole list of basic entries
            IEnumerable<SimplePersonViewModel> rows = context.Persons.Select(r => new SimplePersonViewModel(r));

            // Construct a new view model with these entries
            BaseListingViewModel model = new BaseListingViewModel(rows);

            return View(model);
        }
    }

    public IActionResult DetailRow(int id)
    {
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            // Get only the entry that we are interrested in
            PersonEntity row = context.Persons.Include(p => p.Detail).Single(r => r.Id == id);

            // Construct a new view model with this entry
            PersonViewModel model = new PersonViewModel(row);

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<PersonEntity> Persons { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<DetailEntity> Details { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel(PersonEntity entity)
    {
        Id = entity.Id;
        FirstName = entity.FirstName;
        LastName = entity.LastName;
        IsHandsome = entity.Detail.IsHandsome;
        Address = entity.Detail.Address;
        Email = entity.Detail.Email;
        Phone = entity.Detail.Phone;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsHandsome { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual DetailEntity Detail { get; set; }
}

public class DetailEntity
{

    public bool IsHandsome { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual PersonEntity Person { get; set; }

}

public class SimplePersonViewModel
{

    public SimplePersonViewModel(PersonEntity entity)
    {
        Id = entity.Id;
        FirstName = entity.FirstName;
        LastName = entity.LastName;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class BaseListingViewModel
{
    public BaseListingViewModel(IEnumerable<SimplePersonViewModel> list)
    {
        Rows = list;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SimplePersonViewModel> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `Index.cshtml` view

```
@model BaseListingViewModel

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Id
        </td>
        <td>
            First name
        </td>
        <td>
            Last name
        </td>
        <td>
            Is handsome
        </td>
        <td>
            Go to details
        </td>
    </tr></thead>
    @foreach (SimplePersonViewModel person in Model.Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @person.Id
            </td>
            <td>
                @person.FirstName
            </td>
            <td>
                @person.LastName
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("DetailRow", new {id = person.Id})">Details</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And here is the `DetailRow.cshtml` view

```
@model RelaxationPortal.Controllers.PersonViewModel

Details for @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName (id: @Model.Id)
<br />
Address is @Model.Address and can be contacted using @Model.Phone

@if (Model.IsHandsome)
{
    <span>He <b>IS</b> handsome</span>
}

else
{
    <span>He isn't so handsome</span>
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Wndrr - I think this gives me somewhat of an idea how this could work, but putting it in practice I brutally fail. For starters, IActionResult is not being accepted. I think what I want to achieve could be achieved easier - and yes, I am using EF.
To rephrase/simplify my question: I want to use the index of my products (basically the catalog) to navigate to the page where the product is being ordered. In order to get crucial values passed on to my order (i.e. units) I would need to use an enhanced view model (mainly for the post method, not necessarily for get method).

Comment: First thing first, what do you mean by `IActionResult ` is not being accepted ? Is it refusing to compile ? If so, can you give me more information about the version of MVC you're using ? You can try replacing `IActionResult ` with just `ActionResult ` to begin with

Comment: What in the above example dissatisfies your requirements ? Can you edit your question to add your code attempt(s) and show which part of the **code** you are struggling with ?

Comment: just edited - thank you; I completely fail on the model/controller side